# About Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have difficulty with the proof of this fact:

Prop: Let $L/K$ be an infinite Galois extension. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $Gal(L/K)$. Then $Gal(L/L^H)=\overline{H}$.

---

Proof of [$\overline{H} \subseteq {Gal(L/L^H)}$]:

Clearly we have $H \subseteq Gal(L/L^H)$.
Also, note that $Gal(L/L^H)$ is closed, so we have $\overline{Gal(L/L^H)}={Gal(L/L^H)}$.
Take closure, then we have $\overline{H} \subseteq \overline{Gal(L/L^H)}={Gal(L/L^H)}$.
$\checkmark \checkmark \checkmark$

---

Proof of [${Gal(L/L^H)} \subseteq \overline{H} $]:
Equivalently we will show that if $\sigma \not\in \overline H$, then $\sigma \not\in {Gal(L/L^H)}$:

Let $\sigma \not\in \overline H$.
We know that $\overline{H}$ is closed, so its complement is open.
Also, we know that the topology is Hausdorff.
So there is an open neighborhood of $\sigma$ which is disjoint with $\overline{H}$,
i.e. there is a finite Galois extension $F$, such that $\sigma Gal(L/F)\cap\overline{H}=\emptyset$.
Also notice that
$\sigma Gal(L/F)= \{\tau\mid \tau\restriction_F = \sigma\restriction_F \}$.
Also, the fact that $\sigma Gal(L/F)$ and $\overline{H}$ are disjoint,
implies that
$\sigma Gal(L/F)\cap{H}=\emptyset$.
So we can conclude that $\sigma\restriction_F\neq h\restriction_F$ for any $h \in H$.

> My Question (The point I am stuck in):
> Why there exists an $\alpha \in F$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)\neq \alpha$
> and $h(\alpha)=\alpha$ for any $h \in H$.
> Please explain it very clear, because I am totally confused.

I can not see the reason for the existence of such an element.
If we can find such an $\alpha$, then $\alpha \in L^H$.
So $\sigma \not\in Gal(L/L^H)$.
(Otherwise, $\sigma$ should fix any element of $L^H$,
in particular it should fix $\alpha \in L^H$,
for which we know that $\sigma(\alpha)\neq \alpha$).
$\checkmark \checkmark \checkmark$

---

If I can see the reason for that special question, then everything is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If $h\mid_F$ were to equal $\sigma\mid_F$, then $h$, by what you wrote previously, would appear in $\sigma\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)$ in which case it would be an element in the intersection $H\cap \sigma\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)\subseteq \bar{H}\cap\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)=\emptyset$.

Maybe your uncertainty arises in the imprecise notation with which $\sigma\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)$ is written, note that the $\tau$ here are considered to be inside of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$

Comment: Why there exists $\alpha \in F$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)\neq \alpha$ 
and $h(\alpha)=\alpha$ for any $h \in H$. [If we knew that every $h \in H$ acts on $F$ as identity (I think this is not true), then everytihng is solved.]

Comment: I don't think such $\alpha$ even necessarily exists, there is nothing to stop $\sigma$ from being in $\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)$, and in particular fixing $F$.  The argument you are studying does not require you to think about elements of the field.

Comment: So what you've written is not an answer to my question. And it is a different way to prove the Proposition. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: No, what I have written explains what the proof you are asking about is doing. My previous comment explains that the reason you think that the statement holds is likely false.

Comment: To give an example of why such $\alpha$ need not exist, consider the finite extension $L=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$. We can ignore the topological constraints here since the group is discrete. Let $H=\langle\tau\rangle$ be the subgroup associated to $L/\mathbb{Q}(i)$, and $\langle\sigma\rangle$ the one associated to $K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Then note that we could have chosen F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) on which case $\sigma$ will act trivially

Comment: How your answer implies the existence of such $\alpha$, with the desired property?

Comment: Such $\alpha$ does not exist in general. I’m afraid I cannot be much more clear than I have been above. Try working through the example I’ve given.